# How to let user copy image from Safari and paste it into my app's UIImageView?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView that I let users draw into using their finger. It would be very convenient to permit them to paste as well from other apps, e.g. by pressing a button.

But is such a thing possible without too much trouble?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [UIPasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html):

```
imageView.image = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;
```